# Scalaz |-> counterpart in Cats

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-cats

I noticed that the Scalaz `|->` operator is not implemented in Cats. Is there a function offering similar semantics?

Comment: Do you mean [this here](https://static.javadoc.io/org.scalaz/scalaz-core_2.11/7.2.2/index.html#scalaz.syntax.EnumOps@|-%3E(to:F):List[F])?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin yes

Comment: Well, there is no good reason why `|->` should be in Cats, so it's not in there.

Comment: What's the good reason for it to be in Scalaz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Herding Cats" tutorial [recommends](http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/Enum.html) to use `spire.math.Interval` as Cats/Typelevel's replacement for `scalaz.Enum`.

So try to replace

```
import scalaz.syntax.enum._
import scalaz.std.anyVal._

1 |-> 10 // List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

with

```
import spire.math.Interval
import spire.std.int._

Interval(1, 10).iterator(1).toList // List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```